# pg_search_scope not sort as desc or asc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a little problem. And don't know how to fix it.

I want that after filtering by pg_search_scope happens, I can sort by ascending and descending when clicked.
If I try sort without search, all works fine, but if I used a search(looks in if params[:q].present? at trucks_controller) it's not work :(

## model/truck.rb

```
class Truck < ApplicationRecord
  include PgSearch

  pg_search_scope :search,
              against: [:name],
              using: {
                tsearch: {
                  prefix: true,
                  any_word: true
                }
              }

 #Associations
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :crews

  #Validations
  validates_presence_of :name, :company
  validates_uniqueness_of :name, scope: [:company]
end
```

## trucks_controller.rb

```
class TrucksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_truck, only: [:update, :destroy, :show]
  before_action :load_search_trucks, only: :index

  def index
    paginate json: @trucks, status: :ok, per_page: 10
  end

  private

  def load_search_trucks
    if params[:q].present?
      @trucks = current_company.trucks.search(params[:q]).order_by(params[:sort_by], params[:direction])
    else
      @trucks = current_company.trucks.order_by(params[:sort_by], params[:direction])
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Does this error, or just not work? If it generates an error can you share details? Can you provide the view in your post also, and a sample of what the URL looks like in the browser after you click on the sort link (post search, the one that isn't linking)

Comment: Processing by TrucksController#index as JSON
  Parameters: {"page"=>"1", "sort_by"=>"name", "direction"=>"asc", "q"=>"bmw"}
...Completed 200 OK in 18ms (Views: 5.6ms | ActiveRecord: 3.2ms)
It's API side.